# use android accoutmanager.getAuthToken to fetch accessToken and accessSecret for gmail?

Tags: android, oauth, token, accountmanager

is it possible to use accoutmanager.getAuthToken to fetch accessToken and accessSecret for gmail? I want to avoid doing the oauth dance and leverage on accoutmanager instead....

all codes i have seen is that accountmanager.getAuthToken only returns an authtoken (which i assume is the access token) but no sign of access secret.

i want to use these access token and access secret for smtp authentication.

Comment: i think accountmanager can only do oauth 2.0.. that's right?